# Find pairs of rows with identical values in different columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset some data but got stock at this part. My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(sym_id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("AOL.HH", "ARCH.GA", "ARCH.GK", 
"T.GJ", "T.GK"), class = "factor"), comp = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AOL", "ARCH", 
"T"), class = "factor"), seq_nb = c(18327L, 9952L, 39808L, 
56601L, 44974L, 55302L, 20023L, 24403L, 15529L, 46202L, 57269L
), orig_seq_nb = c(81261L, 72161L, 9952L, 
1276L, 98216L, 16423L, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("bond_sym_id", 
"company_symbol", "seq_nb", "orig_seq_nb"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm looking for a code that would give me back rows which have identical values in different columns but also identical values in another.
The output should give me back

```
Row1  ARCH.GA ARCH 9952  72161

Row2  ARCH.GA ARCH 39808 9952
```

As you can see, the columns "sym_ID" and "comp" are equal for my desired output and the values in "seq_nb" and "orig_seq_nb" match.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We subset the dataset with 3rd and 4th columns, loop through the rows, `order`, get the 1st element, `cbind` with the first two columns, use `duplicated` to find the logical index of duplicate elements and this can be used for subsetting the rows of 'df1'.

```
d2 <- cbind(df1[1:2], apply(df1[3:4],1, function(x) x[order(x)][1]))
df1[duplicated(d2)|duplicated(d2, fromLast=TRUE),]
#  bond_sym_id company_symbol seq_nb orig_seq_nb
#      <fctr>         <fctr>  <int>       <int>
#1     ARCH.GA           ARCH   9952       72161
#2     ARCH.GA           ARCH  39808        9952
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for the small dataset!
When I want to apply this code to a bigger dataset, is there a way to extend the cbind command to other columns as well? And how do I proceed if the columns for the cbind and apply command are not next to each other?

Comment: @fabiusw  Make an index of the columns you want to `order`.  FOr example, if you want to order say, `1, 5, 13, 15` etc, `nm1 <- c(1, 5, 13, 15); nm2 <- setdiff(seq(ncol(df1)), nm1); d2 <- cbind(df1[nm2], apply(df1[nm1], 1, function(x) x[order(x)][1]))` and do the `duplicated` step.  In your original dataset, I am not sure whether we need to get the first element or not i.e.`x[order(x)][1]`